# jquery validator: invalidHander and success both called every time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to add some custom hooks into the invalidHandler and success callbacks, but they seem to be both called whether the input is valid or invalid.  Here's the exact HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../lib/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="my_validator.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="content">
  <form id="my_form">
    <div>
      <p>
        <label for="my_num">Enter a number:</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="my_num" name="my_num" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" class="my_result"></textarea>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the exact JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var my_form = $('#my_form');
  var validator = my_form.validate({
    rules: {
      my_num:{
        required: true,
        number: true,
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
          console.log('invalidHandler called');
          alert('INVALID');
        },
        success: function(label){ 
          console.log('success called');
          alert('valid');
        }
      },
    },
    messages: {
      my_num: {
        required: "Field my_num is required"
      }
    }
  });
  var jNum = $('#my_num');
  jNum.on('change blur', function(event){
    var num_val = jNum.val();
    var result_text = 'Numbered entered = ' + num_val;
    $('.my_result').val(result_text);
  });
};
```

After any change is made to the input field, both messages appear in the console:

invalidHandler called

success called

Why are they both being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`invalidHandler` and `submitHandler`(not `success`) not rules they have to be passed as root level values

You need

```
var validator = my_form.validate({
    rules: {
        my_num: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        console.log('invalidHandler called');
        alert('INVALID');
    },
    submitHandler: function (label) {
        console.log('success called');
        alert('valid');
        return false;
    },
    messages: {
        my_num: {
            required: "Field my_num is required"
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1bypjyt2/)

Comment: For some reason, I thought the handlers were fields under "Rules".  Now I see that they are top level fields in the validate object.  But what I didn't also realize is that it seems I need to have a submit button on the form.  Is there a way to have the validator do the validation on just a "blur" or "change" event, before a submit button is clicked?

Comment: @StefanMusarra, by default, validation will occur on the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` events.